# How to save Unity assests to another drive?

Tags: unity, c#, assets, visual-studio

My C:\ volume has almost no space left.
Therefore I want to transfer all my assets to the volume E:/. And save my new assets automatically on the E:/ volume. I have searched very long in unity for save options of unity assets but nowhere found a setting option for this.

Comment: Usually, new assets are created in sub-directories of your project. So when you copy the project to a location on your E drive and reopen it there, then any new assets should be created there.

Comment: I don't think Unity currently has an option for this feature exactly. For the most part most assets are stored directly in the assets folder (or sometimes streaming assets). The only exception I can think of is when using Addressables or AssetBundles. Personally I find these a bit difficult to work with (I only tried AssetBundles) but basically you can use them to make assets in another project and deploy them like updates to your current project. Not sure how this would work in the editor outside of playmode, but you can load in new models in playmode if needed.